# Android LayoutInflater.inflate adds view to the root parent, and not the parent passed in

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-inflate

Lets say I have a layout with a hierarchy ViewGroups as such A > B > C Where A contains B, and B contains C.

I want to inflate a small partial layout that is supposed to go inside C, so inside my activity I do this:`getLayoutInflator().inflate(R.layout.mySubLayout, ViewGroupC);`

But instead of subLayout getting added to C, it gets added to A. What madness is this?

I even looked at the code in `inflate()`, and it seems to at some point call addView on the passed in parent, so I don't get why this is happening.

I know I can achieve my desired affect by calling

```
v = inflate(R.layout.mySubLayout, ViewGroupC, false);`
ViewGroupC.addView(v);
```

But I'm just wondering why `inflate()` doesnt add the inflated view to the ViewGroup that is passed in as the second parent WHICH IS NAMED ROOT, but instead finds the root parent of the passed in parent.

Is this:

- a) A bug?
- b) Desired behavior but confusing documentation?
- c) Something wrong else where in my code that's causing this?

If b, why is this the desired behavior, what is the intended use case?

it seems more intuitive to me to have a method that inflates a layout and adds it as a child to the viewgroup that it was inflated for.

Comment: p.s. App is a single activity, portrait only app, so there has been design decision made to no use fragments, that is why I am manually inflating small sublayouts at runtime and displaying on screen when needed.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this.